# Include scheduled ( future ) posts in WordPress post navigation ( previous_post_link, next_post_link )

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link, scheduled-posts

Is this possible? How can i change the query for adjacent posts and add 'post_status=future' to display next and previous posts for scheduled ones?

I suppose i should use some kind of filter, but could someone show me how? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `get_{$adjacent}_post_where` filter.

Basically all we are doing is replacing the part of the query that says "find published posts" with "find published or future posts".

```
/**
 * Amend the 'WHERE' clause in the SQL query to find an adjacent post
 *
 * @param required string $where  The default 'WHERE' clause in the query
 * @param boolean $in_same_term   Whether or not the adjacent post should be in the same taxonomy term (not required here)
 * @param array $excluded_terms   The ID's of terms that should be excluded (not required here)
 * @return string                 The updated, custom 'WHERE' clause
 */
add_filter('get_previous_post_where', 'my_add_future_posts_to_nav', 3, 99);
add_filter('get_next_post_where', 'my_add_future_posts_to_nav', 3, 99);
function my_add_future_posts_to_nav($where, $in_same_term, $excluded_terms){

    return str_replace("p.post_status = 'publish'", "p.post_status IN ('publish', 'future')", $where);

}
```

While I can't seem to find any Filter Reference for `get_{$adjacent}_post_where`, there is a [Developer Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_adjacent_post_where/) which you may find useful.

Comment: Worked like a charm ;)